# SYSDATE is implicitly is getting converted to to_date() in SQL developer DML Export

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, date-formatting, dml

I'm trying to export the dml from sql developer(v 17.4) but the date column is not coming as expected.

While inserting the record i used SYSDATE for date field but i think implicitly the sql developer is converting that SYSDATE to to_date(). Here's the Query I'm using to insert-

Insert into table_name (INT_OBJ_ID,INT_OBJ_NM,CREATE_DT,CREATE_USER_ID,UPDATE_DT,UPDATE_USER_ID) values (2016,'RDS_BV_RETURN_MAIL_INFO',SYSDATE,'User01',SYSDATE,'User01');

But in DML Export i'm getting this -

Insert into table_name (INT_OBJ_ID,INT_OBJ_NM,CREATE_DT,CREATE_USER_ID,UPDATE_DT,UPDATE_USER_ID) values (2016,'RDS_BV_RETURN_MAIL_INFO',to_date('09-AUG-23','DD-MON-RR'),'User01',to_date('09-AUG-23','DD-MON-RR'),'User01');

Expexted Export :
Insert into table_name (INT_OBJ_ID,INT_OBJ_NM,CREATE_DT,CREATE_USER_ID,UPDATE_DT,UPDATE_USER_ID) values (2016,'RDS_BV_RETURN_MAIL_INFO',SYSDATE,'User01',SYSDATE ,'User01');

Does anyone know how can we resolve this?

[[My Export wizard screenshots(incase it helps)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va8Xu.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Lja.png)

I tried to find the setting to default implicit conversion but couldn't find any. Even Tried to give SYSDATE in NLS but it expects valid date formate.

Comment: Oracle doesn't know or care whether the date value in that column was originally populated using sysdate or a date literal or a function call etc., it only cares what the actual value is. That is what you see when you query the table, and that is what the export tool used to create the insert statement. Are you concerned because it will set the time part to midnight when you run the import (i.e. execute that generated insert statement); or because you want to change all the values to the *current* date/time at the point you run the import?

Comment: Yes, While importing I want to insert current date for some fields @AlexPoole. So, I'm kind of looking for a solution for that. Thanks for you comment.

Comment: Then you'd need to do one of the things Littlefoot suggested, or add (temporary?) triggers to override the date provided in the insert with sysdate, or replace any `to_date(...)` calls in your insert script with `sysdate`. (I would also still suggest you change your NLS_DATE_FORMAT to include the time elements before you export, or any dates you don't override will still be set to midnight.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export extract what it found in that column. It didn't find `SYSDATE` (as function name), but value returned by `SYSDATE` function at the moment of insert and it was - apparently, for that row - 9th of August 2023.

Export (actually, people who programmed it) chose to use `to_date` function with appropriate format mask: `to_date('09-AUG-23', 'DD-MON-RR')`.

> Though, I'd rather see something different, such as `to_date('09.08.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy')`. You certainly wouldn't be able to insert "AUG" into my database which speaks Croatian - of course, not without additional settings (altering the session to set format model and language).

I don't think you can get `SYSDATE` in export. But, what you *can* do is to omit date column(s) from export: in "Specify Data" step, don't include all columns (`*`) - click the pencil button and uncheck date column(s). Then, on target side, either set column's default value to `sysdate`, e.g.

```
alter table target_table modify date_column default sysdate;
```

or populate it manually after insert, e.g.

```
update target_table set date_column = sysdate where date_column is null;
```

Comment: The date format used by sqldev in these statements is what it finds in it's NLS settings.

Comment: Right; but there's no guarantee that target database has the same NLS settings, @gsalem. That's why I'd rather see more "neutral" format mask. Thank you for comment!